After update to Ubuntu 24.04, sound quality is broken when Samsung Smart Monitor is connected
After upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04, sound quality in websites like YouTube, HBO Max, TuneIn worsened: sound playback speed constantly gets faster (maybe 200% of normal), then slower (maybe 50%), and this repeats constantly, making listening / watching / Zoom calls impossible.
Nothing helped:

rebooted - the same
replaced PipeWire with PulseAudio - the same
tested on various web browsers, standalone apps (e.g. FreeTube, VLC - even offline, Zoom) - the same issue
there are no processes eating all CPU
internet is fast (400 mbps)
EDIT: after some further investigation: it happens only on sound card embedded in Samsung smart monitor connected to the laptop via HDMI (laptop internal card is ok, usb external card is ok, monitor's native smart tv apps have no problem with sound quality, using different HDMI cable doesn't help, disconnecting the monitor from power and connecting again doesn't help) - it seems as if something went wrong after the upgrade with the driver responsible for sending sound to such a monitor

Any ideas what's can be going on here? Downgrade or reconfigure the driver somehow?

Does this happen on Ubuntu too, or only Kubuntu?

No idea, I had Kubuntu 23.10, upgraded to 24.04. Technically I can install Gnome desktop, but it's still Kubuntu, not Ubuntu

After some more investigation:

laptop internal sound card - works
USB external sound card - works
the problem is only when Kubuntu laptop is connected to Samsung smart monitor (with built-in sound card and speakers). I tried using a different HDMI cable (problem still exists), or or using the apps like YouTube installed directly on monitor (no problem), so the problem seems to be in driver responsible for communication with the monitor.


Please avoid commenting on your own question. Edit your question instead to add new information and clarifications.

"It's a shame that Linux in 2024 still has problems with basic multimedia playback, and update actually made it worse :-( I thought that multimedia problems in Linux are thing of the distant past." For most folks, such problems are in the distant past. Your problem is not universal. Opinions distract from your technical question. I'm commenting on the opinion instead of asking for diagnostic information.

Finally I found the answer myself: it seems that Kubuntu update process updated kernel to a broken version (6.8.0). I downgraded kernel version to 6.5.0-28 and sound on the Samsung smart monitor's speakers is great again.
How to downgrade kernel version? Can be done via console, but I used 2 3rd party tools: "Mainline Kernels" to ensure it's installed, then "Grub Customizer" to select the version permanently in Grub.
Unfortunately the solution isn't perfect - we can't stick to an older kernel forever, some fix has to be provided to the newer kernels.

confirmed. Have the same issue on a Dell monitor and 6.8.0-31-generic

Now that a few days have passed to allow other users to answer, you can mark your own solution here as the accepted solution to your question (click the checkmark icon to the left).

Confirmed. I've downgraded to Linux 6.6.51-060651-generic to fix choppy sound.
